# What is the best approach to read from both Web.config and appsettings.json in a .NET Standard library?

Tags: nuget, .net-standard

We have an old .NET Framework nuget package built with .NET Framework that reads settings from Web.configs files on .NET Framework projects using the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` class. Now, we need to migrate it to .NET Standard to be able to use it on .NET Core projects also.

Is there an elegant way to try to find and read settings from both Web.config files when running in .NET Framework, and from  appsetting.json when running on a .NET Core project? Does it make sense?

Also, it makes sense to have 2 different nuget packages, one for use only on .NET Framework projects and another to use only in .NET Core projects?

The main goal is to read setting independent of the .NET version it is running on.